# wpa-supplicant error while compiling android ICS for huawei U8818 device

Tags: android, android-source, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

- I successfully compiled the android ICS source code and able to run on emulator.
  after this milestone I had planned to flash it on a huawei device.

  - I downloaded the device configuration from link https://github.com/Dazzozo/android_device_huawei_u8818.But when I execute the command **make -j4** I am getting the following mentioned error.

  **`make: *** No rule to make target`out/target/product/u8818/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/lib_driver_cmd_wext_intermediates/lib_driver_cmd_wext.a', needed by `out/target/product/u8818/obj/EXECUTABLES/wpa_supplicant_intermediates/LINKED/wpa_supplicant'. Stop.`**

I am googling for almost 15 days.posted on various forums and groups including xda-developers ,android-porting etc but no help.Please can anyone suggest me what to do?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download this and copy wifi directory to your device directory(device/brand/device-name/)

https://dl.dropbox.com/s/bxxfatctb879799/wifi.tar.gz?dl=1

It sorted out the problem for me...

:)

Comment: thanks for your precious answer I haven't tested on real build but you deserve acceptance so accepted your answer